# Join tables with Two foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am searching for a real scenario problem that I faced last night while joining two tables with foreign keys. Actually I want to get all values from second table on behalf of foreign key.

Here are my two tables let suppose:

```
table1 (id_user_history(PK),id_user(FK), order_no, p_quantity)
table2 (id_shoping_cart(PK), id_user(FK),order_id, prod_quantity)
```

Now I want to get all values from table2 by joining these tables with table1(id_user(Fk)) and table2( id_user(FK))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table2 t2
LEFT JOIN
        table1 t1
on      t1.id_user = t2.id_user
```

all records from table 2 and only those record which match on table 1.

SQL is mainly set logic.  Here's a link which helps visualize. 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple join fits the bill:

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
left join
        table2 t2
on      t1.id_user = t2.id_user
```

Comment: I think he wants an `INNER`?

Comment: @mattytommo up to the user but when I see requirements indicating all values from table X, that implies outer join.  if it was inner user may not  be getting all values from table X.

Comment: @xQbert In that case your tables are the wrong way around as table1 rows will appear and only those that match from table2. OP wants all records from table2.

Comment: @mattytommo so that means he needs to use a RIGHT join given the order of tables, not inner.